# Failed to Get Objects from Json List without Title Names

Tags: c#, json, list, observablecollection

I want to get the objects  list of time stated in `JSON` list:

```
["09:30","11:25","00:00"]
```

This the C# code:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetAlarmList() 
{
    return (from t in _connection.Table<Medication>()
            select t.alarm_time).ToList();
}

var r = db.GetAlarmList();
var alarm_result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(r);
ObservableCollection<> t = new ObservableCollection<>(alarm_result);
```

It has not title like Time but it's just like that how can i get them into an `ObservableCollection` or `List`

Comment: I don't understand what failed and what you want. Please show also the code

Comment: I have provided it @GiladGreen

Comment: Please show value of `r` (the entire value) so we can replicate the problem

Comment: do you want to convert a JSON to c# list ??

Comment: But you do not have a json. You have an `IEnumerable<string>`.. What is the content of each item in the `IEnumerable`

Comment: Ok , what i want is to get the Items in a GetAlarmList() , so i first made it json serialized then i deserialized again , but i dont know how to get each time separately

Comment: @IdrisStack - still, the given data example - is it of a single item of the `IEnumerable<string>` or of all of it. Basically - can you show what you have in a given row under the `alarm_time` column

Comment: So the is the time stored in the Sqlite table , i want it to be in an ObservableCollection or List

Comment: It is of a single item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the separate values of the items use `Split`:

```
_connection.Table<Medication>().Select(r => r.alarm_time)
           .AsEnumerable()
           .Select(r => r.Substring(1, r.Length - 2).Split(','));
```

If you want to flatten the collection (and not have an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` use `SelectMany` instead

Comment: How can i return it , because i want to return it as a string to attach it to a Label

Comment: @IdrisStack - your question is not clear.. what is the desired output? A single string? or a collection of strings?

Comment: ok dont worry i got it thanks , but of you dont mind can you give me you mail or skype id thanks.

Comment: @IdrisStack - I prefer not... All SO communication should only take place through SO

Comment: Ok no problem just wanted you to guide me sometimes